# R Session Aborted and R encountered a fatal error | RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, fatal-error, abort

I was using RStudio for a long time and it was ok with me, but before one day when I try to compile a code, it gives this message "R encountered a fatal error" and it forces me to restart RStudio again and the problem still.

the code I used just call two libraries:

```
library(Rtsne)
library(ggplot2)
```

And this I was run it before multiple time and it's ok.

Any help, please?

Comment: Can u try running the code on R console

Comment: The same problem :( it tells me 'R session aborted, R encountered a fatal error, The session was terminated' @akrun

Comment: What version of R are you running? 
Also I installed 'RTsne' package and loaded the libraries like you did. No problem on my RStudio.

Comment: This is the version I used, 'R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)' @Shreyas

Comment: Can you try 'resetting RStudio' as mentioned at this link - https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State

Comment: Also there may be a problem with RStudio workspace.
After backup, you can use this command - `rm ~/.Rdata`

Comment: I tried the resetting link but still nothing change, about 'rm ~/.Rdata' it tells me 'no such file or directory' @Shreyas

Comment: did you figure this out & resolve?

Comment: No unfortunately :( @Shreyas

Comment: try installing a new R version/delete the existing workspace (.Rdata) by searching the workspace location?

Comment: I delete R and RStudio and download the new version, the problem still :( that's really strange @Shreyas

Comment: Then i guess it must be a problem with workspace. Check if RStudio has necessary write permissions to the workspace directory.

Comment: The only solution is that I download it on another machine and get rid of all this headache :) @Shreyas

Comment: ohh..ok. LOL.
other option might to try it in a VM :)

Comment: Im having the same problem and it seems to be related to Rtsne

Comment: Oooh, I discover the reason because the huge data that I tried to plot with Rtsne but when I tried small one the error disappeared @HappyMachine

Answer (score 2):

This issue can occur in many instances and the causes might be multiple. I run a very large dataset relating to the single cell transcriptome, and the error can occur unexpectedly and randomly. Sometimes this will happen but can be fixed after restart the session, sometimes this will not happen running the same code.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same "R session aborted" after updating R. I thought it was R's fault, then I tested the script in terminal and everything worked fine. I tried reinstalling Rstudio (same version) and it still failed.
The issue was solved by installing the lastest Rstudio from `https://dailies.rstudio.com/`.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem when running the first chunk in every RMD file I create, specifically when clicking the 'run current chunk' arrow sign.

One way to avoid this is to run the first chunk after highlighting the code in lines, and simply clicking the 'run selected lines' command on the top right-hand corner. From my experience the subsequent chunks can be run without issue by clicking the 'run chunk' arrow.

Comment: I think what is happening here is that R clears unused objects every once in a while - I read every 10 seconds but it seems slower than that to me. So what is happening when you hit the play button is that you aren't giving RStudio the time needed to clear memory before moving on to the next thing, but when you highlight the code chunks individually and run sections of code, you are slowing the process down and giving RStudio time to clear memory. If you tried to put gc() for garbage collection in between code chunks, I'll bet you could hit the play button without issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it appears to be related to a conflicting xfun package source compilation. To resolve this problem, I removed and then reinstalled the package. Since the issue seems to stem from a compilation problem, you should installing both the binary and source versions.

```
install.packages("xfun", type = "binary")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by uninstalling all the packages in R and then reinstalling them again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).